# Why is PHP double escaping this string?

Tags: php

I have an issue that has something to do with the version of PHP.

Here is the raw string passed into the url:

```
?path=/2013/6/14/1371207330-SBM1_Today\'s Touch Strongsville.xls
```

In PHP 5.3.21, when I echo $_GET['path'], it returns (wrong):

```
/2013/6/14/1371207330-SBM1_Today\\\'s Touch Strongsville.xls
```

In PHP 5.3.15, it returns the correct version (correct):

```
/2013/6/14/1371207330-SBM1_Today\'s Touch Strongsville.xls
```

How do I fix this so that the later version of PHP doesn't add the additional escaping?

**For Future Readers**

The error had nothing to do with the version of PHP, but rather the configuration of two different php installations. In my case, my local version had a php.ini config with magic_quotes off, while the customers shared hosting provider (HostGator) had it turned on.

Comment: google `magic_quotes`

Comment: Are you sure you need the backslash in your raw string?

Comment: Are you sure both versions of PHP are using the same config (php.ini) file, and exact same web server versions and configurations?  I'm not seeing any obvious changes in PHP's change log which would have any effect on the URL escaping between those versions.

Comment: GRR. HostGator has magic quotes on by default. Time to hunt down how to disable it. This is why I hate shared hosting...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was (see comment by IMSoP) one of the horrible features of PHP. It's called "magic quotes" and can be enabled and disabled in the configuration file. [Here's an article on disabling it.](http://www.php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

In short, put this into your `php.ini`:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Comment: More accurately, this *was* a horrible feature of PHP, which has been discouraged for years, and was removed completely in version 5.4. Just in case anyone thinks they can use it as an excuse to bash the language.

Comment: @IMSoP: But I like bashing PHP! :(

Answer (score 0):

check if you have magic quotes turned on:

```
get_magic_quotes_gpc();
```

If this function returns true then that's the problem, you have to turn it off in php.ini
http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php